# Why did an immigration office left his booth for a while while processing my exit from Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, airports

When I was exiting the Schengen area last year, the immigration officer left his booth for 10 to 15 minutes without telling me the reason why. When he returned, he just stamped my passport without asking any questions or clarifications from me. There were also no additional marks or notes in my passport aside from the stamp.

Until now, I'm still confused about what's happened since my entry to the Schengen area 2 weeks preceding my exit had been hassle-free. I'm sure that I didn't commit any crimes or visa violations during my stay there. Can anyone share their insights as to what happened?

Comment: Impossible to say. It could be that the official had doubts as to the authenticity of your passport, showed it to a senior or specialist colleague, and got told that it was genuine. No need to explain to you that he had doubts. Or your name and face seemed familiar from some notice, he checked, and found that you don't match after all. Again no reason to tell you.

Comment: Or he just needed a comfort break...

Comment: @Traveller at least the pages from the passport weren't missing.